# Vk Sdk для Android

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Хотел подключить использование профиля VK в своё андоид-приложение, добавил VK sdk для андроид версии 2.2.1 и столкнулся с проблемой - нет класса VkApi, а так же многих других. Однако вся документация, что есть, была написана под более раннюю версию (около 1.6.5). Собственно, обращаюсь к Вам: может быть кто-нибудь уже решал данную проблему или может что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk тут есть пример в sample папке для 2.2.1